# Changing IP behind custom name servers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have 2 servers; 1 old and 1 new. I'm moving accounts between the two servers. What i have done until now is made a new custom NS for new server based on the new domain name I have used for the servers hostname: `a/b.thewhitecloud.in`

My old servers NS are `a/b.easycloud.net`

Now i don't want to ask each client to change their nameservers since that list is pretty long. So is there some foolproof way of changing the server without affecting the accounts. IE. if I change the NS IP's of easycloud NS will it work seamlessly or am I looking at downtime? There are more than a 100 domains involved and I cant take any risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your wording, this is the actual question:

> Can I change the value of the `A`/`AAAA` records associated with the existing `NS` records without downtime?

Yes, that is one option. Another option is to down the interface of one of the old servers, and bring its IP address up on the server intended to replace it. (assuming they live on the same network) Both approaches have their disadvantages, but where possible I would encourage moving the IP address over changing the DNS records.

- Moving the IP address itself gives you the option of quickly moving the IP address back if you encounter a problem, but you may need to flush the ARP cache of attached network hardware. This is generally what I would recommend.
- If the replacement server doesn't live on the same network, you'll need to change the `A`/`AAAA` record of the old server to point at the IP address of its replacement. It's a good idea to lower the TTL of that record ahead of time in order to speed up the transition. The main disadvantage is that if you need to roll back to the old server, you'll have to go through another record change+cache expiration cycle.

  - Traffic will slowly shift from the old server over to the new server as the TTL expires in remote server caches, but keep in mind that some configurations may enforce minimum TTL values that are higher than the one you have chosen. I would wait at least a day just to be safe, regardless of how low the TTL is.
  - Do not expect *all* DNS traffic to shift, but >95% of your traffic should. You'll continue to see random DNS traffic from devices which have previously scanned your network and discovered the open DNS listener, but this is to be expected.
  - **Do not** power off or otherwise disable the nameserver software running on the old server until you are confident that the traffic shift has completed successfully.

Regardless of the approach you select, I strongly recommend having some form of graphing solution in place in order to observe the state of your environment before and after the change. Packet graphs are a starting point, but I also recommend graphing the ratio of response codes returned by your server. If you see a noticeably higher ratio of `REFUSED` or `SERVFAIL` responses from the new server (compared to traffic from the old server), **you should roll back immediately**.

Comment: Hi Andrew, 

I am going ahead with the second option. I have lowered the TTL for the A records. Now as I understand the next step would be to change the A record entries in my WHM and at my domain registrars Child Name servers.